# How to merge multiple tables in Power BI while also appending a a new column that contains the name of the table ?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m, powerbi-desktop

I figured out how to take my audit tables and combine them..

Audit Company
Audit Contacts
Audit Referrals etc..

So Now I need an additional column in my merged table so I know what table the data came from ? How can I do this in power query?

Comment: You could add a table name column to each table before you merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before merging the tables add a new column to each table you want to merge:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Source", "Original table", each "Audit Company")
```